# Memory Layout during downcasting in c++

Tags: c++

```
class Parent {
public:
    void sleep() {cout<<"Paren::sleep";}
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    void gotoSchool(){cout<<"chil::gotoSchool";}
};


int main( ) 
{
  Parent parent;
  Child child;

  // upcast - implicit type cast allowed
  Parent *pParent = &child;  //OK.

  // downcast - explicit type case required 
  Child *pChild =  (Child *) &parent; //OK due to typecast but not safe when we call child specific method

  pParent -> sleep();
  pChild -> gotoSchool(); //Undefined but works ok on VS08

  return 0; 
}
```

**Question:**

In the above code `pChild -> gotoSchool();` is undefined as per standard. By the word *undefined*  , it means it *may* or *may not* work. It worked for me. But my question is why did it work? It shouldn't have. I cannot visualize the layout object in memory.

//Parent object doesn't even know anything about gotoSchool method, so how come a pointer to Parent object still prints gotoSchool. The question here is not about the undefined behavior, its more about how can it even know about the 
gotoSchool method, so **even by sheer luck** it shouldnt call the gotoSchool method to print Child::gotoSchool.

```
Parent         Child
-----------     -------------
|         |     |           |
|  sleep  |     |   sleep   |
|         |     | gotoSchool| 
-----------     -------------
```

Ofcourse the object doesnt contain inside it the member functions but only data members. The above diagram is just for explanation.

Answer (score 4):

> But my question is why did it work?

Because the way your compiler was implemented happens to lead to that behaviour.

> It shouldn't have.

If you mean that a compiler shouldn't allow that behaviour, well... standard doesn't require that.

It may, it can, and it did.

> How it works

I don't have the source code of visual studio at hand so I can't tell you exactly how it works. But generally speaking, member functions are implemented as regular functions, except with an extra parameter which contains the address of the object. The location of the function itself in the memory is not associated with the memory of the objects. The compiler knows exactly where the code for the function is.

You might even be able to do `((Child*)nullptr)->gotoSchool();` and observe the same (undefined) behaviour.

There is no obvious reason why it couldn't have the observed behaviour.

> I cannot visualize the layout object in memory

The memory layout of the object is irrelevant to the function because the function never uses any of the object's memory.

Comment: No my question is not related to why compiler allows or why it works, but _How_ it works. What is the memory layout which leads to printing the statement child::gotoSchool.

Comment: @anurag86 well, I don't have the source so I can't tell you exactly *how* visual studio works but I've expanded to answer that.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the compiler breaks down the classes into C-structs and functions that gets `this` pointer as parameter. then it compiles the code the same way C is compiled - structs + global functions. this is the common way to compile object oriented code. of course, there are more "tricks" like virtual table and such.

since your member function doesn't touch any member function/variable (= uses `this` pointer), it worked, because although `this` is entierly wrong, it is left unused.

assembly wise, your code looks like

```
  void gotoSchool(Child* this){cout<<"chil::gotoSchool";}
   gotoSchool(&parent);
```

again, like you mentioned - this is still Undefined Behaviour althought there is some logic why it still works.

Comment: _"then it compiles the code the same way C is compiled - structs + global functions."_ Ehm... not really. I mean, kind of. But not really. Only if you're discussing at a layer below calling conventions.

Comment: well, there are other actions especially if other C++ specific features are involved, like templates, but this "kind of" is what I mean - the function gets `this` as a bridge between the function and the member variables.

Comment: @David: Even if it passes as _this_ , i wonder how it works still. You can call it this way `pChild -> gotoSchool(pChild)` and receive it this way `void gotoSchool(Child* mythis) {  mythis=this;}` . Before the assignment `mythis=this` you can see both are pointing to same address, so it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: if you want to really know how function call works, you'll have to learn assembly. but anyway, even with assignments and such,  your member function doesn't use `this`. this is the only reason why it's working (and it's still UB). as soon as the function starts using `this` you'll expirience much more strange behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It works, because you don't actually use anything from the instance member, you just print a static string.

The function is not virtual, so when you call gotoSchool it just directly calls it.

(Tested with VS2015) You could also call gotoSchool on a nullpointer, as long as you don't actually try to reference any members it will work.

```
Child* pChild = (Child*)0;
pChild->gotoSchool();
```

The compiler knows pChild is of type Child and it knows that gotoSchool is not virtual, so it directly calls it regardless of the value inside pChild.

## What is the memory layout?

Logically, it is empty.
You have neither virtual members for which a vtable would be required nor do you have member variables.

Practically, it might contain type information for RTTI and/or some padding bytes, but none of these are relevant for your gotoSchool function.

**Non-virtual functions are not part of the memory layout!**

## Implementation of classes in C++

There are a lot of better explanations, but in short, member functions are implemented as normal functions with a hidden this parameter.

Your function is internally just

```
gotoSchool(Child* this)
```

In your example, `this` references to a Parent, **but you never use it, so it doesn't matter**.

## Undefined <> Actual Implementation

You reason that it shouldn't work because it is undefined.
But *undefined* is meant literally, ANYTHING is possible and allowed for undefined behavior.
I recommend this article (and a few others) by Raymond Chen:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx

Comment: _It works, because you don't actually use anything from the instance member, you just print a static string._  even this static string is stored somewhere in your memory(code section) and to access it compiler should have some hint/info which in this case it should not have had.   Calling the methods on `Child *pChild=0` used to work previosuly on VS2005 but not on 2008.

Comment: @anurag86 The call from the null ptr works for me with VS 2015.

Answer (score -1):

It worked because you were actually pointing to a `Child` object.  Casting a pointer to a `Child` doesn't change it to `Parent*`, it just tells the compiler to look at the memory at the pointer as a `Parent*`.  Casting that same pointer back to a `Child*` again doesn't change anything.   If you 'upcast' to a thing it isn't, the underlying memory won't be right, but upcasting to something you know it is will work.

But, to answer your question about memory layout, it's generally:

```
lower address <---where a pointer to the object points to
    [PTR to VTABLE]
    [data members for parent]
    [data members for child]
higher address
```

So you can look at the memory as a Parent*, or a Child* and the data members will be in the 'right spot'.   Functions don't matter because the VTABLE (or the linker knows) where those are.

Comment: _It worked because you were actually pointing to a Child object._ Nope, i am not pointing to a child object. I am just making the compiler believe that i am pointing to a child object. Secondly, the layout you showed applies only for data members and in this case it doesnt really matter as a member function is being accessed and not data member. Lastly, VTABLE doesnt exist here.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I didn't read carefully enough.  I though you were casting to a parent and then back.   It works because the member function you call doesn't access any child data, and the member function you called isn't virtual